# Bootstrap-form gem, strange error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

Here is the code for a form created with the bootstrap-form gem for rails.

```
<%= bootstrap_form_tag(user_sessions_path) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label_tag :email %><br />
    <%= f.text_field_tag :email %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label_tag :password %><br />
    <%= f.password_field_tag :password %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit_tag "Login" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This throws an error: no implicit conversion of symbol to string on the first line of the form containing the user sessions path. Not sure why this is happening

Comment: Can you post the link of the gem you are using?

Comment: @Nobita gem 'bootstrap_form'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you have to be explicit about the `url`. Like this:

```
<%= bootstrap_form_tag(url: user_sessions_path) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label_tag :email %><br />
    <%= f.text_field_tag :email %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label_tag :password %><br />
    <%= f.password_field_tag :password %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit_tag "Login" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Check the [source code](https://github.com/bootstrap-ruby/rails-bootstrap-forms/blob/master/lib/bootstrap_form/helper.rb). You can see as how the `bootstrap_form_tag` method, expects a `Hash` parameter:

```
def bootstrap_form_tag(options = {}, &block)
  options[:acts_like_form_tag] = true

  bootstrap_form_for("", options, &block)
end
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. Kind of silly that you have to be so explicit, but definitely worth the little extra time.